# Extending dataframe by adding 0

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following

```
#   Year A B
# 1 2000 1 1
# 2 2002 0 2
# 3 2005 0 1
```

I would like to add the years in between to generate an output like:

```
#   Year A B
# 1 2000 1 1
# 2 2001 0 0
# 3 2002 0 2
# 4 2003 0 0
# 5 2004 0 0
# 6 2005 0 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid` and `merge` with `base R`

```
out <- merge(expand.grid(Year = min(df$Year):max(df$Year)), df, all.x = TRUE)
out[is.na(out)] <- 0
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c(2000, 2002, 2005), A = c(1, 0, 0), B = c(1, 2, 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `complete` and `full_seq` in `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)

complete(df, Year = full_seq(Year, 1), fill = list(A = 0, B = 0))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
   Year     A     B
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2000     1     1
2  2001     0     0
3  2002     0     2
4  2003     0     0
5  2004     0     0
6  2005     0     1
```